# Как организовать хостинг на своем сервере

Tags: хостинг

Доброго времени суток, купил домен, есть свой сервер, чтоб не тратить деньги и не заказывать хостинг услуги у провайдера хочу организовать хостинг у себя на сервере. Подскажите как?

Или, подскажите, как правильно спросить поисковик, или скиньте ссылку, только не на английском. Спасибо.

Comment: У Вас статический ip? Операционную систему хотя бы напишите.

Comment: @dimka3210 вангую, что дебиан/убунту, статический айпи, телепаты наконец вышли из отпуска.

Comment: Сначала, нужно понять - кому Вы будете продавать услуги хостинга, и как их будете продвигать на рынке хостинговых услуг.

Answer (score 5):

**Здесь представлен список основных шагов, которые вам понадобится выполнить.**

1. Настраиваете свой домен, чтобы он указывал на IP вашего сервера.

Для этого идете в его настройки, удаляете записи типа А которые ведут на чужие адреса (скорее всего их одна или две, если нет, то надо разбираться зачем они там) и добавляете запись типа А на свой IP `@ A XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX YY`, где ХХХ это IP вашего сервера, YY - время жизни TTL.

С почтой здесь отдельный разговор. Если будете подключать, например, mail.ru для бизнеса, то у них в документации все хорошо прописано.

Подробнее прочитать про типы записей можно, например, [здесь](http://dns-master.ru/simple/records.html) или на [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8B_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9_DNS).

Пример:
[image: Пример настроек]

2. (Опционально) Если у вас IP не статический.

В это случае вы будете часто встречать фразу "делегирование домена". В этом нет ничего страшного. Это просто задает место хранения настроек вашего домена.
Запись делегирования выглядит так: `@ NS xxxxxx`, где xxxxxx это адрес DNS хостинга.

Например, мой доменный регистратор не имеет возможности обновлять соответствие IP домену программно, поэтому использую DNS хостинг, а на роутере прописан скрипт обновления DDNS раз в час. Т.о. при смене IP в худшем случае через час он обновится. Можно поставить интервал обновления и другой, просто мне такой больше подходит.

Обновлять DDNS можно хоть с самого сервера, это уже зависит от способа подключения (он подключен напрямую и имеет белый IP, либо через промежуточное оборудование и не имеет белого адреса).

3. (Опционально) Проброс портов (NAT)

Скорее всего, ваш сервер стоит за роутером или фаерволом. Тогда вам придется создать правила проброса портов на внутренний IP вашего сервера.

Например, чтобы открыть порт 80 на ваш веб сервер, вам придется создать правило наподобие такого:
`Входящий порт: 80, Протокол: TCP, Действие: netmap (название может отличаться в различном софте), На адрес: вашего сервера, На порт: Порт, который прослушивает ваш веб-сервер`

Пример:
[image: Пример моего правила для IIS с порта 8080 на порт 80 веб сервера]

4. Установка сервера

Здесь уже зависит от вас. Какую операционку вы установите и какие службы вы на нем развернете (веб-сервер / сервер кс 1,6 / или еще что-то)

Пример для IIS (самый простой чтобы было от чего отталкиваться):
[image: Пример для IIS (самый простой чтобы было от чего отталкиваться)]

В консоли IIS кликнуть ПКМ на сайты и выбрать добавить веб-сайт. Выбрать название, указать папку где он лежит, написать домен (по которому к нему обращаться), указать порт. Этого достаточно чтобы запустить простой статический сайт.
(Должна быть установлена служба IIS. Пример ниже. Самый простой способ установить необходимые компоненты - выбрать Asp.Net. Вместе с ним установятся и некоторые другие компоненты. **Не забыть кликнуть "Статическое содержимое"** для стилей и других статических файлов)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

5. (Опционально) создание доменов 3 уровня вида lalala.domain.com

Очень полезная вещь для веб-сервера. Для создания поддомена требуется добавить запись типа А в настройки домена. Пример: `lalala А XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX YY`, где ХХХ это IP вашего сервера, YY - время жизни TTL.

**Скрины настроек приведены для ознакомления и на профессионализм исполнения не претендуют!**

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно поставить/настроить, как минимум

- mysql, сервер бд (пакет mysql-server, особой настройки не требует до появления серьезной нагрузки)
- php, интерпретатор сами понимаете чего (php, php5-fpm, php-mysql и все аналогичное из результатов `apt-cache search php`)
- nginx/apache, веб-сервер, который будет передавать запросы "снаружи" интерпретатору и отдавать статику. Для apache могут потребоваться моды libapache2-mod-*, nginx со всему расширениями ставится как пакет `nginx-full`, но обычно не требуется ничего кроме стандартного пакета.

Comment: а еще веб-панель для доступа к учетным записям хостинга для админа и клиентов и бэкап-сервер. Ну и логи.

Comment: А почему обязательно mysql/php? Может он хочет только статику хостить. Или python использовать.

Comment: @dzhioev, так то можно вообще предположить IIS+MSSQL+ASP.NET. Будет исходить из самого стандартного и всем нужного.

Comment: @deivan, я опять поработаю телепатом: под хостингом автор имел в виду саму возможность осуществления обработки запросов. Но сама панель управления не помешает, конечно.
@dzhioev, потому что в этом случае, скорее всего, эти требования были бы указаны. И еще потому что питон на 99% стоит по умолчанию.

Answer (score 0):

Альтернативный ответ, поскольку операционная система не указана.

Вам надо установить:

- SQL Server Express 2014/2016, он бесплатный, но имеет ограничения, которые, впрочем для большинства сайтов несущественны.
- IIS Web Server. Входит в состав Windows Server любой версии.
- .NET обновить до последней версии, сейчас 4.6.2.

Всё, можете разрабатывать сайты на ASP.NET MVC и Entity Framework.